# Is there a use for hashCode() of a mutable object?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I have been going through sources of Java Collections framework and noticed that `AbstractList` and `AbstractMap` return the sum of their elements' hash codes as their own hash code value. This makes List and Map implementstions return distinct hash code values depending on the contents of the collection.

The only use for the `hashCode()` method I know is even distribution of elements into buckets inside data structures that use hashing e.g. `HashSet` and `HashMap`. However, the `Set` and `Map` contracts specify:

> The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

and:

> The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

These contracts make objects that may return distinct hash values depending on their state dangerous to use in sets and as keys in maps. That makes me wonder:

1. Is there a point in returning a variable hash value?
2. Would not it be better to return a constant (per object class) hash value?
3. What use can the `hashCode()` method have besides being used in hash collections?

Comment: Having a constant hashcode for an object would violate its [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--). For example, if you lock the hashcode to a value the first time its called, then two different instances which are equal could have different hashcodes.

Comment: @resueman, yes but you can generate it in a constructor upon instantiation like its done for String objects.

Comment: You'd still have the same issue. Two objects with different hashcodes could be modified to be equal to each other.

Comment: @resueman, sorry I was not clear: I meant that you would need to generate it based on final fields, so hash would not change.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a point in returning a variable hash value?

A data structure doesn't know if you change the hashCode of a key or element. Do so will corrupt the data structure.  However, if you mutate the object before adding it to a hash collection, and afterwards not change it, this will work.

> Would not it be better to return a constant hash value?

Yes, but that constant must be consistent with equals, in which case the only way to return a constant to not alter any of the field used to create the hashCode().

> What use can the hashCode() method have besides being used in hash collections

It can be used to identify individual objects for debugging/logging purposes, though this is more useful if you are using the builtin Object.hashCode() or System.identityHashCode(). It's a quick way to check if two objects are the same reference e.g.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

useBB(bb);
useBB(bb2);

public static void useBB(ByteBuffer bb) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" - Using bb " + System.identityHashCode(bb));
    // do something
}
```

If you see two threads using the same ByteBuffer you might have a problem....

> you can generate it in a constructor upon instantiation like its done for String objects.

String's hashCode is generated on demand to reduce the overhead of creating Strings where you don't need the hashCode. Note: having a String with a hashCode of 0 is expensive though rare unless someone attempts to create strings with a hashCode of 0.

Similarly, the hashCode of Object is generated on demand. It is stored in the header on Oracle/OpenJDK with an initial value of 0 for unset, but is set to 1 - 2^31-1 on first use.

This program benchmarks the cost of `Object.hashCode()` by resetting the hashCode to 0.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Performance-Examples/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/unsafe/HashCodePerf.java

This program benchmarks setting the Object.HashCode() with a simpler strategy.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Performance-Examples/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/unsafe/FasterHashCodePref.java

> I meant that you would need to generate it based on final fields, so hash would not change.

This is not enough of a guarentee for the hashCode not changing e.g.

```
class A {
    final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    public int hashCode() {
        return strings.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Your fields need to be both `final` and immutable. to ensure the hashCode won't change.  However, if you don't change them, they won't change either.

Comment: I meant that String hash is generated based on final fields)

Comment: @RobertMugattarov yes, the hashCode is based on fields which are only set in the constructors.

Comment: `It's a quick way to check if two objects are the same reference` Absolutely not. The default behavior of Object#hashCode() isn't even mandated by the API, even if it typically is the address: `This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.` Even at that, you can't rely on this because if somebody overrides this method, then it no longer means the address anymore, even if you are using a Java implementation that uses addresses as default return values.

Comment: An example of where having the same hashCode doesn't mean you have the same object https://twitter.com/PeterLawrey/status/856448017376923648 All these strings have a hashCode of 0

Comment: Even the `identityHashCode` is not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a point in returning a variable hash value?

Yes.  A class's `hashCode()` method should be consistent with its `equals()` method.  If a class defines instance equality in terms of mutable state, then its `hashCode()` should also be defined in terms of that same mutable state.

Such objects are rarely appropriate for inclusion in hash-based collections, but they *can* be used in such collections if one is careful to avoid mutating them while they remain inside.

> Would not it be better to return a constant hash value?

`Object.hashCode()` in fact does this, supposing that you mean "constant" in a per-instance sense.  If you do not override `equals()` then there is no good reason to override that constant hash value, either, but if you *do* override `equals()` then you really should to provide a consistent `hashCode()` implementation.

> What use can the hashCode() method have besides being used in hash collections?

If a class caches its computed hash code then comparing instances' hash codes can serve as a cheap "maybe equal" test, allowing bypass of a more costly exact equality test in many cases where the objects in question are in fact unequal.

Similarly, if a hash code is defined in terms of mutable state, then a change in hash code is a positive indication that that state has changed (though the converse is not true).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there a point in returning a variable hash value?

No. But if the user is careful not to modify the list and its contents when using the list as a key in a hash table, then the hash value won't vary and the hash table operations will work correctly. It's certainly dangerous, because the user becomes responsible for ensuring that the hash code doesn't change when needed, but it is possible.

> 2. Would not it be better to return a constant hash value?

Not really.  It's true that it guarantees that the hash code value will always respect its contract (that 2 equal objects always return the same hash code), even if the list changes... but what's the point of using a hash table if all the elements get put in the same bucket because of a constant hash code?  Performance would be terrible, better to use another collection type at that point.

> 3. What use can the hashCode() method have besides being used in hash collections

Nothing else really. Some make creative uses of the hashcode value, but they are often invalid and based on an incorrect understanding of what a hash code means.

Answer (score 0):

> The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is
>   changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object
>   is an element in the set.

If we translate this quote to what it means in practice, things become clearer. In plain language:

> A java.util.Set should not be used to store objects with mutable
>   identities. In this usage two objects A and B are identical for the
>   purpose if `A.hashCode() == B.hashCode()` and both `A.equals(B)` and
>   `B.equals(A)` return true.

So the answer to the questions:

1. There is no point in returning a variable hash code.
2. A hash code must be constant among equal objects. A hash code that is constant per class does not break the contract but is useless for performance.
3. There is no use for an overridden hashCode() method outside hash collections.